# How to debug transformAndConcat in Google guava?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, guava

I'm trying to understand the transformations within a collection written in existing app, which heavily uses Google Guava library.

To be more specific, I can't step into **transformAndConcat** method in my Intellij IDEA.

I'm using JDK 7. So normally lazy and terminal operations can't be used. Or I'm wrong?

How can I debug this method?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "normally lazy and terminal operations can't be used."  I can get that debugging that sort of logic can be tricky, going up and down through the various comparator implementations, but I'm not sure what sort of answer you're hoping for here.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to step into the guava transformAndConcat method itself, you can use "F7" or click the "step into" button in the debug window to step into the transformAndConcat method.

[IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 Help:Stepping Through the Program](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/stepping-through-the-program.html)